# Where is my T-SQL Editor toolbar in VS 2008 Professional?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I cannot find the "T-SQL Editor" in vs 2008 professional.  Is this not available in this version?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it requires Database Edition.